# Units in group rings

Tags: gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, p-groups, group-rings

Let $F$ be any field with $p$ elements and $G$ be any finite $p$-group, combining together they form a group ring $FG$. And $V(FG)$ denotes group of units of coefficient-sum equal to 1 in $FG$. We have $V(FG)=N\rtimes G$ for some subgroup $N$, iff we can have a group homomorphism $$f:V(FG)\rightarrow G,$$ which fixes elements of  $G$ and sends the complement part to $1_G$.

My question here is assuming that one of two above conditions hold for some finite $p$-group $G$, what can we say about any subgroup $H$ of $G$ ?

I mean, will it satisfy any of the above two equivalent conditions ? I am not able to show it . According to me, this condition will not get inherited for any general subgroup $H$. There must be some extra condition on the subgroup, which I am trying to get. Please help me out this situation.

Comment: What's a "$p$-element"?

Comment: @YCor I am sorry if it is bit confusing but it simply means field consists of p number of elements.